# Apache | AB | socket: Cannot allocate memory (12)

Tags: apache, testing

I'm doing a **ab** test

```
 ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://www.mysite.com/
```

this is the output

```
Benchmarking www.mysite.com (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
socket: Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

I've tried it several times sometimes it breaks even earlier. I have alot of free memory 
this is from **top** while im running **ab**

```
Mem:    524288k total,   269968k used,   254320k free,        0k buffers
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running ab on VPS?
I think that's restricted the max socket resource by ISP.